# JCIFS SMB Library - Error when trying to list domains (.listFiles)

Tags: java, networking, samba, smb, jcifs

I have the following code, which lists the domains found on my network.

```
try{
    //Listamos todos los dominios de la red smb
    raiz = new SmbFile("smb://");
    dominios = raiz.listFiles();
} catch(SmbException e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

It throws me an

> jcifs.smb.SmbAuthException: Logon failure, unknown username or bad
>   password.

The problem is that I know that the code should work because sometimes (like 1 of 15 runs), it lists the domains like it should:

> DOMAIN1/
>   DOMAIN2/
>   DOMAIN3/

Also tried the code on my home network and it works everytime.

Anyway, if I try to list the files of the specific domains:

> raiz = new SmbFile("smb://DOMAINX");

it works correctly with 2 of the 3 domains of the network. In the other one, happens exactly the same that before - just works correctly like 1 of 15 runs-- so I'm guessing the problem is in the configuration of a concrete domain.

I'm stuck. Does somebody know what could be happening or how could I get closer to the solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to tel for sure but it seems like you do not have access rights for the DC of DomanX. Listing domains is a non-deterministic process where the result depends on which PC was used as "master browser". This role mat be switched between PCs and that explains why you sometimes succeed (when MB is from D1 or D2)  and fail otherwise (when BM belongs to D3).

It is possible to tell more with wireshark captures of both successful and failed runs